# Load oEmbed iframe within ajax call

Tags: ajax, oembed, iframe

I'm trying to load oembed shortcode loaded via ajax.

The problem is that the oembed shortcode seems to work as I have a blockquote instead of the instagram link. However the blockquote is not replaced by an iframe.

There should be a javascript function searching for blockquotes and replacing it by an iframe but it is not fired because I don't load all the page ?

Does anyone know how to fire this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I needed to call specific plateform function to fire the process. In my case Instagram and Facebook :

```
window.instgrm.Embeds.process();
if(typeof FB!=="undefined"){
  FB.XFBML.parse();
}
```